# Sending response after fs.readFile has finished executing iteratively

Tags: node.js, callback, promise, fs

I have the following code

```
var express = require('express');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
var path = require("path");
var langs = fs.readdirSync({directory having multiple directories});
var arr = [];
for(var v in langs){
    var filename = config.path.storage + "/" + langs[v] +"/assets/_assets.json";
        fs.readFile(filename, "utf8", function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write(data);
        //res.end();
    });
}
res.end();
```

What I want to do is, once all the files in the directories (lang in this case - langs contains: ***[ 'ar-dz', 'en-gb', 'en-us' ]***) are read, I want to do a res.send() to the client.

I tried to promisify the 'fs' module via 'bluebird' module. I assume the callback in fs.readFileAsync() is causing the problem, is there a way around it?

Comment: Becoz `res.end()` will get executed before any of the `res.write` calls are executed

Comment: Okay, I'm re-formatting the code.. I understand why the Can't set headers is happening, but the actual problem, as the title says, I need a way around executing my piece of code after iteratively executing readFile()

Answer (score 1):

`Can't set headers after they are sent.` is occurring because you are calling `res.write()` after you've called `res.end()`.  This happens because the async response to `fs.readFile()` comes later after your `for` loop is done.  Instead, you need to use your promises to coordinate the result of your async operations and when they are all done, you can then send your response with all the data.

You can use your Bluebird promise library to do that like this:

```
fs.readdirAsync(...).map(function(file) {
    return fs.readFileAsync(file, 'utf8');
}).then(function(arrayOfData) {
    res.send(arrayOfData.join(""));
}).catch(function(err) {
    // send some error response here
});
```